# youtube comments threading and google plus authentication

Tags: youtube-api

To pull in replies to a youtube comment the documentation states you will need to make a second call to the Google+ API's comments:list. Will this call require a separate google API authentication request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following as a reference. https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments.

I was able to use the youtube api authentication token I made with original request. I just had to have the following permissions requested.

https://gdata.youtube.com

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me